# Record Type change

Tags: visualforce, record-type

Can we change the record type of a record once assigned.
Using standard functionality. 
If i click on editing a record i am not able to edit the record type to which it is assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to change the record type of a record once assigned. Here's the information on how:

[Changing a Record's Record Type](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_recordtype.htm&language=en)

Answer (score 1):

There is a field **[Object Name] Record Type** you can change it. If this field is not showing  you can add it after editing Layout(in the right side). Just add the record type field to Layout then you can easily update record type.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers, thought it should be mentioned that you must make sure the user has appropriate permissions for the record type.  They can only change the object to one of the record types their profile has access to.